# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'AbpEditions'.'

Tags: asp.net, database, backend

I am new in the database & backend area, and there is a web application, which in the "aspnet-core" file of the app; when I Run a solution on Visual Studio, after connecting to the Azure SQL, the error

```
Exception User-Unhandled  
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'AbpEditions'.'
```

would you please give a hint about how to handle the mentioned issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

the field that you are using in the controller is call "AbpEditions" so checkout the name of the table in the database they should match.